# how do i integrate spree commerce with spree hub?

Tags: spree

I would like to integrate spree commerce with the hub. I can't find any tutorials from the spree site. Can someone give me tutorials to do so. Or guide me with it! Thank you.

Comment: The Spree Hub is a commercial product.  You'll need to contact support@spreecommerce.com for assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating Spree Commerce with Wombat (the Hub's new name) can be done with this Gem, which has a decent README on how:

https://github.com/spree/spree_wombat